# Issue with HttpListener after migrate to .net 4.5.1 from 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, iis-8, httplistener

We have a project using a HttpListener on  port 80.
It works perfectly on .net 3.5 in production and in development.
For dependency reason, we have to migrate it to .net 4.5.1. The project works fine in development but not when we put into Azure.

The other part of the upgrade is the migrating from IIS 7.5 to IIS 8.

The main code of the app. First the base listener :

```
public abstract class BaseHttpListener
{
    private IPEndPoint HttpEndPoint;
    private IPEndPoint HttpsEndPoint;
    private HttpListener Listener;


    protected BaseHttpListener(IPEndPoint http, IPEndPoint https = null)
    {
        HttpEndPoint = http;
        HttpsEndPoint = https;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(Listen));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        // Create a HTTP listener. 
        Listener = new System.Net.HttpListener();
        Listener.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("http://{0}/", HttpEndPoint));

        if (HttpsEndPoint != null)
        {
            Listener.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("https://{0}/", HttpsEndPoint));
        }

        Listener.Start();

        while (Listener.IsListening)
        {
            var context = Listener.BeginGetContext(ListenerCallback, Listener);
            context.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        }
    }        

    private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var httpListener = ar.AsyncState as HttpListener;
        if (httpListener.IsListening == false)
            return;

        var context = httpListener.EndGetContext(ar);
        try
        {
            Process(context);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogManager.Instance.Fatal(exception, String.Concat("Fatal exception occurs when try to process '", context.Request.Url.ToString(), "'"));

            //We should try to send a error to the client
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
           context.Response.StatusDescription = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError.ToString();
           context.Response.Close();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void Process(HttpListenerContext context);

    public void Stop()
    {
        Listener.Prefixes.Clear();
        Listener.Close();
    }
```

The simple index handler :

```
   public class IndexRequestHandler : RequestHandler
{
    public IndexRequestHandler(String handledPath)
        : base(handledPath)
    {

    }

    public override void HandleRequest(System.Net.HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        var html = @"<!doctype html>
                    <html lang='en>'
                        <head>
                            <meta charset='utf-8'>
                            <title>It's ready</title>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                            <h1>It's ready</h1>
                        </body>
                    </html>";
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
        context.Response.ContentLength64 = bytes.LongLength;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html;charset=UTF-8";

        try
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            context.Response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.Instance.Error(ex, "IndexRequestHandler.HandleRequest");
        }
    }
}
```

And I can give you other exemple, details if required.

An other important things is I run a cmd command : telnet X.X.X.X 80 and it return me something but when I test http://X.X.X.X in chrome, I get nothing

Thanks for your help !

Comment: A bit confused. You have a HttpListener and what relationship does it have to IIS? I would have expected you are using HttpListener in place of IIS. This also doesn't strike me as an Azure-related issue.

Comment: Yes you have right, may be the upgrade of IIS does not have an impact. But I don't know what is wrong... And because IIS is the web server by default, I prefer to say it. What I m sure it's : it's works fine on my laptop (win 7) but not on the server (win server 2012 R2)

Comment: Do you receive an exception when you start your httplistener? If yes, please copy-paste it here.

Comment: ... and you cannot start an httplistener listening on port 80 or 443 if the port is used by IIS.

Comment: No exception on the start. And I check that IIS don't use the port 80 and the port 443